# NOT ABLE TO ACCESS URL https://testdev01.azurewebsites.net

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am not able to access "https://testdev01.azurewebsites.net"
Its showing "The service is unavailable"

> _errorData: undefined _sourceErrorLevel: undefined baseTypes: ["t","MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]  code: undefined data: 1 errorLevel: 2
>   extension: fx handled: undefined innerErrors: ["message: Failed to
>   retrieve the blade definition for 'ActivityLogBlade' from the
>   server.\r\nmessage:Manual require of the following modules failed;
>   ["_generated/Blades/ActivityLogBlade" : {Error: Couldn't load
>   "_generated/Blades/ActivityLogBlade" at
>   "https://afd.hosting.portal.azure.net/websites/Content/5.12.34.475/Scripts/_generated/Blades/ActivityLogBlade.js?retryAttempt=1.0371554125639133";
>   error code 404, message: Not Found}];\r\nstack:
>
> ### RPC_Exception ##\nError: Failed to retrieve the blade definition for 'ActivityLogBlade' from the server.\r\nmessage:Manual require of
>
> the following modules failed; ["_generated/Blades/ActivityLogBlade" :
>   {Error: Couldn't load "_generated/Blades/ActivityLogBlade" at
>   "https://afd.hosting.portal.azure.net/websites/Content/5.12.34.475/Scripts/_generated/Blades/ActivityLogBlade.js?retryAttempt=1.0371554125639133";
>   error code 404, message: Not Found}];\n at new r
>   (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/qLnxN0oZGQC0.js:18:790)\n at
>   u (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/qLnxN0oZGQC0.js:11:1296)\n
>   at Object.tt [as QReject]
>   (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/qLnxN0oZGQC0.js:11:1405)\n
>   at
>   https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/qDdhDKs5uKzm.js:4:5443\r\nFrom
>   RPC: fx -> WebsitesExtension
>   (MsPortalFx.Internal.Constants.RpcMethods.entryPointGetBladeDefinition)\r\n(Callstack
>   capturing is not enabled. Use ?trace=diagnostics to enable it.)\r\n"]
>   message: Unable to locate blade 'ActivityLogBlade'. Search
>   path:'[0]WebsitesExtension-[1]ActivityLogBlade'.

Comment: Control F5 on the Browser fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

The error (503)- 'The service is unavailable' may be caused by the application level issues, requests taking a long time; application using high memory/CPU or application crashing due to an exception. Firstly, review the application from this front to isolate the problem.

To fetch more details on the error, you could access Kudu console to check the log. You could access http://yourwebappname.scm.azurewebsites.net and review the debug logs.

To access the Application Event Log, use the Diagnose and solve problems blade in the Azure portal. 
1.  In the Azure portal, open the app in App Services.
2.  Select Diagnose and solve problems.

Also, to fetch more details on the error, you can always enable logging. Please check out the documentation '[Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log)' for a detailed steps on enabling & fetching the logs.

You may also scale-up your App Service Plan and then check to see if that makes any difference. 
If feasible, you may restart the WebApp and then check to see if that helps.